# Set Eclipse as the default editor for opening a file

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to set Eclipse as the default program for open certain types of files? I'd like to set it as the default program for editing .java and .js files.

Comment: I can open the file in Eclipse on Ubuntu using this command: eclipse (path of file I'm trying to open)

Comment: Further information on this topic is available here: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=associate%20eclipse%20with%20java%20files&oq=associate%20eclipse%20with%20&gs_l=hp.11.0.0i30j0i8i30j0i22l2.231072.235069.3.237016.27.18.2.6.6.1.475.6067.2-2j9j5.16.0...0.0...1c.vXMMm5X5hTE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=cda1f62fcb8b192d&biw=1301&bih=656&pf=p&pdl=300

Comment: This tutorial explains how to do this on Mac OS X: http://bewarethepenguin.blogspot.com/2010/08/setting-up-java-files-to-automatically.html

Answer (score 3):

The normal way of setting a default program to open a certain type of files would work:

Right click a certain .java / .js file (any file of the type you want Eclipse to open by default) `->` Open With `->` Choose default program `->` Choose Eclipse (you may need to browse and find the Eclipse executable file (the launcher)).

Do this for .java and .js files and you're good to go.

Comment: Is this specific to a certain type of operating system, or does it apply to all operating systems?

Comment: Also, where is the Eclipse executable usually located on Windows?

Comment: This is specific for Windows (all versions). As for Linux, the "Open with" option should be in the Properties tab after you right-click a certain file.
As for the Eclipse executable file (the launcher), I suggest you search your computer for "eclipse.exe", as its location depends on where you saved the Eclipse download package to.

Comment: On Linux (Ubuntu 12.04), Eclipse doesn't even show up under the list of installed applications.

Comment: I think the reason why it doesn't show up under the list of installed applications is because Eclipse is not installed - when I installed the latest version of Eclipse few weeks ago, it was downloaded as a .zip file and all I needed to do was unzip it and I was able to use Eclipse. The folder it was unzipped to is the folder where the Eclipse launcher is located in my computer, and no installation was ever required.

Comment: I have installed Eclipse on both Windows and Linux (on my dual-boot computer) - it runs as expected on both platforms.

Comment: Were you able to find the location of the Eclipse launcher?

Comment: The Eclipse launcher icon is on the sidebar on Ubuntu. Are you specifically referring to the executable file that launches Eclipse?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4290/discussion-between-amiregelz-and-anderson-green)

Answer (score -2):

Install this plugin on eclipse : 
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/default-text-editor

Comment: According to the description at the site, this does the opposite of what was requested.  The question asks to define it specifically for .java and .js files.  Your plug-in is for any text files that do not have an assigned default editor.  But in general, please see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers for guidance on recommending software.